# F# execution order against SQL database

Tags: f#, f#-data

F# noob here. This might be something stupid, please forgive my lack of understanding.

I am using FSharp.Data to access SQL on the back end.

Have the following MSTest code:

```
[<TestMethod>]
member this.EmailReads_Test_InsertOneGetAll () =
    let initialCount = TblEmailReadHelper.all() |> Seq.length
    TestTool.tblEmailReadDbCreate |> ignore // creates new record
    let lastCount = TblEmailReadHelper.all() |> Seq.length

    Assert.IsTrue( lastCount > initialCount, lastCount.ToString() + " <= " + initialCount.ToString())
```

If I run the Test Explorer and try to debug this, code works fine.

If I run the Test Explorer in run with other tests I get the following output

```
Assert.IsTrue failed. 9 <= 9
```

Which leads me to believe the line

```
let initialCount = TblEmailReadHelper.all() |> Seq.length
```

Is getting executed when I am doing the Assert

```
Assert.IsTrue( lastCount > initialCount, la...
```

Instead of the beginning of the test.

I know for a fact the add works and I am not running tests in parallel, so other tests are not messing with my count, but I know also when the first count happens it is getting the record that was added.

What simple concept I am not aware of?

Comment: are you sure you're not running it in parallel, or even if running sequentially (i believe the default for MSTEST), other tests are not doing something? you can print the output of the initialcount to make sure what is its value before and after the `let`. Or switch to xunit and see what happens (but it does run in parallel by default).

Comment: @s952163 I am sure is not in parallel.I even did another test where I print out the lists and the initial list will have the new record in it. I am trying to find out execution order here.

Comment: `Which leads me to believe the line...` - I believe it should be eagerly evaluated and that something else is going on here. This seems easy to troubleshoot - can't you just run this single test in isolation and look at the number of records in the DB before and after?